# TortoiseGit command shortcuts in window toolbar

Tags: tortoisegit

When I installed TortoiseGit (on Windows 7), I got a number of command shortcuts added to the toolbar of windows explorer, as in the image below, and I think they are really useful:

[image]

How do these appear? Because I tried to install TortoiseGit (same version) on other PCs (same OS) and those shortcuts just do not want to appear. I cannot find anything in the Settings that show or hide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those shortcuts only appear on Windows 7 and Vista and only if Git versioned folders are accessed using the Git library (cf. [Working with libraries](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/working-with-libraries); if you can't find the TortoiseGit library, it can be re-created in [TortoiseGit settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html)).